# Update derived property in WPF with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

What pattern can be used to ensure a property gets updated when in the UI when it concatenates multiple sources.

For example I have a string property for the window title. It presents the application name (const string), the assembly version (readonly string), and an instance property of a type that gets loaded based on user input.

Is there a way to make the title property subscribe to the instance property so that when the instance is loaded the title automatically updates?

Right now when the recipe is loaded it updates the title property. But I'd like to reverse this so that the the recipe doesn't know about the title. It simply broadcasts that it is loaded, then anything that needs to react to a recipe being loaded would handle the event in isolation.

What design pattern is suited for this?

Comment: Err.. have you heard about bindings? INotifyPropertyChanged? Together they give "the title property subscribe to the instance property so that when the instance is loaded the title automatically updates" effect

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I edited the title of your question slightly to make it better fit our guidelines, and to match your actual question a little more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following class in my MVVM library to allow property changes to cascade to related properties.  Feel free to use it if you think it will be useful to you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AgentOctal.WpfLib
{
    public class PropertyChangeCascade<T> where T : ObservableObject
    {

        public PropertyChangeCascade(ObservableObject target)
        {
            Target = target;

            Target.PropertyChanged += PropertyChangedHandler;
            _cascadeInfo = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        }

        public ObservableObject Target { get; }
        public bool PreventLoops { get; set; } = false;

        private Dictionary<string, List<string>> _cascadeInfo;

        public PropertyChangeCascade<T> AddCascade(string sourceProperty,
                                                   List<string> targetProperties)
        {
            List<string> cascadeList = null;

            if (!_cascadeInfo.TryGetValue(sourceProperty, out cascadeList))
            {
                cascadeList = new List<string>();
                _cascadeInfo.Add(sourceProperty, cascadeList);
            }

            cascadeList.AddRange(targetProperties);

            return this;
        }

        public PropertyChangeCascade<T> AddCascade(Expression<Func<T, object>> sourceProperty,
                                                   Expression<Func<T, object>> targetProperties)
        {
            string sourceName = null;
            var lambda = (LambdaExpression)sourceProperty;

            if (lambda.Body is MemberExpression expressionS)
            {
                sourceName = expressionS.Member.Name;
            }
            else if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression unaryExpression)
            {
                sourceName = ((MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand).Member.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("sourceProperty must be a single property", nameof(sourceProperty));
            }

            var targetNames = new List<string>();
            lambda = (LambdaExpression)targetProperties;

            if (lambda.Body is MemberExpression expression)
            {
                targetNames.Add(expression.Member.Name);
            }
            else if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression unaryExpression)
            {
                targetNames.Add(((MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand).Member.Name);
            }
            else if (lambda.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.New)
            {
                var newExp = (NewExpression)lambda.Body;
                foreach (var exp in newExp.Arguments.Select(argument => argument as MemberExpression))
                {
                    if (exp != null)
                    {
                        var mExp = exp;
                        targetNames.Add(mExp.Member.Name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Syntax Error: targetProperties has to be an expression " +
                                                    "that returns a new object containing a list of " +
                                                    "properties, e.g.: s => new { s.Property1, s.Property2 }");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Syntax Error: targetProperties has to be an expression " +
                                            "that returns a new object containing a list of " +
                                            "properties, e.g.: s => new { s.Property1, s.Property2 }");
            }

            return AddCascade(sourceName, targetNames);
        }

        public void Detach()
        {
            Target.PropertyChanged -= PropertyChangedHandler;
        }

        private void PropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> cascadeList = null;

            if (_cascadeInfo.TryGetValue(e.PropertyName, out cascadeList))
            {
                if (PreventLoops)
                {
                    var cascaded = new HashSet<string>();
                    cascadeList.ForEach(cascadeTo =>
                    {
                        if (!cascaded.Contains(cascadeTo))
                        {
                            cascaded.Add(cascadeTo);
                            Target.RaisePropertyChanged(cascadeTo);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    cascadeList.ForEach(cascadeTo =>
                    {
                        Target.RaisePropertyChanged(cascadeTo);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ObservableObject` is just the base class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You should be able to substitute your own fairly easily.

You use it like this:

```
class CascadingPropertyVM : ViewModel
{
    public CascadingPropertyVM()
    {
        new PropertyChangeCascade<CascadingPropertyVM>(this)
            .AddCascade(s => s.Name,
            t => new { t.DoubleName, t.TripleName });
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetValue(ref _name, value);
    }

    public string DoubleName => $"{Name} {Name}";
    public string TripleName => $"{Name} {Name} {Name}";
}
```

The line in the constructor hooks up cascading the change of the `Name` property to `DoubleName` and `TripleName` properties.  By default, for performance reasons, it won't check for loops in the cascade, so it relies on you not creating them.  You can optionally set `PreventLoops` on the cascade to `true`, and it will make sure that `PropertyChanged` is only raised once for each property.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is ideal, but my solution is to handle the property changed event provided by MVVMLight

```
    private Model.Recipe _recipe;
    public Model.Recipe Recipe
    {
        get { return _recipe; }
        set { Set(ref _recipe, value); }
    }

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return "Test " + Recipe.MyProperty; }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        PropertyChanged += MainViewModel_PropertyChanged;
        Recipe = new Model.Recipe();
    }

    private void MainViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "Recipe": RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty"); break;
        }
    }
```

Don't really like that MainViewModel_PropertyChanged will become a massive switch statement that handles all changes. An alternative approach would be to use messenger.

```
    private Model.Recipe _recipe;
    public Model.Recipe Recipe
    {
        get { return _recipe; }
        set { if (Set(ref _recipe, value)) { Messenger.Default.Send(value, "NewRecipe"); } }
    }

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return "Test " + Recipe.MyProperty; }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<Model.Recipe>(this, "NewRecipe", NewRecipe);
        Recipe = new Model.Recipe();
    }

    private void NewRecipe(Recipe obj)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
```

The benefit of this approach is that if MyProperty is in a different ViewModel it will still receive the notification and they will not be tightly coupled.  Anything that needs to handle a recipe change will be able to register for the message and receive notifications without giant methods that handle every property change event.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'd like to reverse this so that the the recipe doesn't know
>   about the title. It simply broadcasts that it is loaded, then anything
>   that needs to react to a recipe being loaded would handle the event in
>   isolation.

Sounds like Steven's Cleary Calculated Properties is what you need: https://github.com/StephenCleary/CalculatedProperties

I already answered similar question in more details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41444180/1553641

This library is magic. In fact I would recommend it for **any** MVVM project whether it is new or old, it is trivial to adopt the calculated properites incrementally and enjoy instant benefits.